# How to display IPv4 address using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I found this code on youtube and follow exactly like it. The MAC address and the nic name showed but the IPv4 wont show. Basically i want to show ipv4 address for all network interface inside my computer with the either its connected or not. Here the code

```
  Private Sub getinterface()
    'get all network interface available in system
    Dim nics As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    If nics.Length < 0 Or nics Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No network interfaces found")
        Exit Sub
    End If


    'if interfaces are found let list them. first clear the listview items
    ListView1.Items.Clear()


    For Each netadapter As NetworkInterface In nics
        'next lets set variable to get interface properties for later use
        Dim intproperties As IPInterfaceProperties = netadapter.GetIPProperties()
        'now add the network adaptername to the list
        ListView1.Items.Add(netadapter.Name)


        'now get the mac address of this interface
        Dim paddress As PhysicalAddress = netadapter.GetPhysicalAddress()
        Dim addbyte As Byte() = paddress.GetAddressBytes()
        Dim macaddress As String = ""


        'now loop through the bytes value and change it to hex
        For i = 0 To addbyte.Length - 1
            macaddress &= addbyte(i).ToString("X2") 'change string to hex
            'now let separate hex value with -except last one
            If i <> addbyte.Length - 1 Then
                macaddress &= "-"
            End If

        Next

        'ount item in listview
        Dim icount As Integer = ListView1.Items.Count

        'use try
        Try
            With ListView1.Items(icount - 1).SubItems
                .Add(macaddress)
                '.Add(intproperties.UnicastAddresses(2).Address.ToString)
                .Add(intproperties.AnycastAddresses(2).Address.ToString)

                .Add(intproperties.UnicastAddresses(2).IPv4Mask.ToString)

                .Add(intproperties.UnicastAddresses(0).Address.ToString)
                .Add(intproperties.UnicastAddresses(1).Address.ToString)
                '.Add( IPAddress.Parse(a).AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork )
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Next
    'now lets make auto size columns
    ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    getinterface()
End Sub
```

Is there a solution for this code or there is another simpler way to do this for display all nic name with its ipv4 address? currently using visual basic express 2010 express

Answer (score 0):

Use WMI queries for this - it will be a lot simpler.

There are some useful classes available - `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` & `Win32_NetworkAdapter` for getting these details. For easy WMI code creation, search for `WMI Code Creator`

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace WMISample

    Public Class MyWMIQuery

        Public Overloads Shared Function Main() As Integer

            Try
                Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher( _
                    "root\CIMV2", _
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration") 

                For Each queryObj As ManagementObject in searcher.Get()

                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------")
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration instance")
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------")

                    If queryObj("IPAddress") Is Nothing Then
                        Console.WriteLine("IPAddress: {0}", queryObj("IPAddress"))
                    Else
                        Dim arrIPAddress As String()
                        arrIPAddress = queryObj("IPAddress")
                        For Each arrValue As String In arrIPAddress
                            Console.WriteLine("IPAddress: {0}", arrValue)
                        Next
                    End If
                    Console.WriteLine("IPEnabled: {0}", queryObj("IPEnabled"))
                    Console.WriteLine("MACAddress: {0}", queryObj("MACAddress"))
                Next
            Catch err As ManagementException
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
            End Try
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```